# Interfaces, dependency injection and base classes

Tags: c#, oop, generics, dependency-injection

I have 2 interfaces both extending the same interface

```
public interface IInterface1 : IGeneral
public interface IInterface2 : IGeneral
```

These interfaces are implemented by 2 classes with 2 different base classes

```
public class Class1: BaseClass1, IInterface1
public class Class2: BaseClass2, IInterface2
```

`IInterface1` and `IInterface1` have some methods and properties that are identical and some are different

IDENTICAL

```
Action<byte[], int> OnEvent1 { get; set; }
Action<Type1> OnEvent2 { get; set; }
public int Method1();
void Method2();
```

DIFFERENT

```
IInterface1
void MethodDifferent2();

IInterface2
Task MethodDifferent2();
```

I am using these interfaces in a program this way

```
private IInterface1 objectType1;
private IInterface2 objectType2;
```

....

```
    if (config.test != null)
    {
        switch (config.test)
        {
            case "Type1":
                objectType1.Method2();
                break;
            case "Type2":
                objectType2.Method2();
                break;
            default:

                break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        objectType2.Method2();
    }
```

But I am forced to have two objects and switch cases

Is there a way (probably a pattern of oop) to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the deal with DI?

Comment: Sorry, I fail to understand your question.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible but I would like to have one object that "changes its type" depending on the configuration

Comment: @vernou I use DI to instanciate the object objectType1= obj.Method<IInterface1>(param1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One uses design patterns to address particular design concerns. From the OP it's not clear what forces are at play. The code in the OP describes the methods `IInterface1.MethodDifferent2` and `IInterface2.MethodDifferent2`, but never uses them.

While all that description indicates an attempt to supply a [minimal, reproducible  example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's not clear what the actual problem is.

## Simplification

As given, it's possible to simplify the code to this:

```
if (config.test == "Type1")
    objectType1.Method2();
else
    objectType2.Method2();
```

This has the same externally visible behaviour as the OP.

## Chain of responsibility

Given, however, that more may be at stake, one alternative may be the [Chain of Responsibility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) design pattern

One might, for example, define an interface like this:

```
public interface IConfigHandler
{
    void Handle(Config config);
}
```

with two implementation:

```
public sealed class ConditionalConfigHandler : IConfigHandler
{
    private readonly IGeneral general;
    private readonly string configValue;
    private readonly IConfigHandler next;

    public ConditionalConfigHandler(IGeneral general, string configValue, IConfigHandler next)
    {
        this.general = general;
        this.configValue = configValue;
        this.next = next;
    }
    
    public void Handle(Config config)
    {
        if (config.test == configValue)
            general.Method2();
        else
            next.Handle(config);
    }
}
```

and

```
public sealed class DefaultConfigHandler : IConfigHandler
{
    private readonly IGeneral general;

    public DefaultConfigHandler(IGeneral general)
    {
        this.general = general;
    }

    public void Handle(Config config)
    {
        general.Method2();
    }
}
```

You can then get the same observable behaviour by chaining objects like this:

```
new ConditionalConfigHandler(
    objectType1,
    "Type1",
    new ConditionalConfigHandler(
        objectType2,
        "Type2",
        new DefaultConfigHandler(objectType2)));
```

Clearly, as shown by the above simplification, this is overkill for the OP as stated, but may be applicable in the actual scenario.

Another option is a variation over the [Composite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) design pattern; it would look quite similar to the code shown here.

Answer (score 0):

If Method1 and Method2 are in IGeneral, you can call both using

```
private IGeneral objectType1, objectType2;
```

Another way is to use the dynamic type

```
private IInterface1 objectType1;
private IInterface2 objectType2;
...
dynamic objectType = objectType1;
objectType.Method2()
objectType = objectType2;
objectType.Method1()
```